# Postfix Blacklist multiple EMails Reject

Tags: email, postfix-mta, blacklist

is there a possibility to block multiple EMails with* or % like this:

Emails I want to block:

```
test123@domain.com REJECT
test243@domain.com REJECT
test173@domain.com REJECT
test923@domain.com REJECT
```

My idea:

```
test*@domain.com REJECT
```

or

```
test%@domain.com REJECT
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible. May i know how you are currently trying to use this file with postfix. For eg.  `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/file`

Comment: Yes using /etc/postfix/blacklist with postmap hash:/etc/postfix/blacklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya that is possible. You can use `pcre` lookup type to achieve this.

```
#/etc/postfix/blacklist.pcre
/^test.*@domain.com$/   REJECT
```

You can use this in your `main.cf` as `pcre:/etc/postfix/blacklist.pcre`.

PS: Your postfix server will need to compiled with `pcre` support. You can confirm the same by typing `postconf -m` which should give `pcre` in output. Hope that helps. More info about Postfix lookup tables [here](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html)